# Why is the unique constraint missing when filling the datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I have the following table in SQL server

```
projects
   id(PK, int, not null)
   name (varchar(255), not null)
   public_key_token (varchar(50), null)
```

I have added a unique constraint to the `name` column using

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.projects  
ADD CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (name);
```

which results in a `Unique, Non-Clustered` index on the table (trusting SSMS).

In the code I'm retrieving the table data using

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from " + DbTabName, con))
{
    using (DataTable table = new DataTable(DbTabName))
    {
         DataTable dt = adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
         PkColumns = dt.PrimaryKey.Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
         AutoIncrementColumns = dt.PrimaryKey.Where(c => c.AutoIncrement).Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();
         UniqueColumns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.Unique).Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToList();

         ...
    }
}
```

The PKs and AutoIncrement columns are OK but in `UniqueColumns` I only get the PK column again.
The `name` column arrives in C# without the `Unique` constraint.

Changing the `SchemaType` to `Mapped` did not alter the result.

Why do I lose this constraint on the way to C#? Am I missing something on the SQL Server side or in C#?

**[UPDATE]**
@Tim-Schmelter's answer only solves the problem half way.

Just adding the index did not work. Also adding the index when the PK on the `id` column exists doesn't work.

The only way I got it to work was delete the table, recreate it without any key and indexes and then add the `unique` index as in Tim's answer. However, after adding the PK for the `id` column once more I'm back to the old behaviour that only the `id` is listed as unique column.
This is really weird.

Comment: In some (odd) places, some pieces of code distinguish between *column* constraints and *table* constraints. Since the separate `ALTER TABLE` created a table constraint, is it present in the `DataTable`s `Constraint` property only? (Since a table constraint could apply to multiple columns, it wouldn't be appropriate to mark individual column's `Unique` property if they were part of a multi-column unique constraint)

Comment: From my (limited) experiments, it would appear that the system only processes (up to) one constraint, and the PK by preference over others. I can't find any documentation to say whether that's expected behaviour.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's also what I think right now. For now I'll just mark the `name` column as PK and leave the `id` out. Maybe I can get some additional feedback on MS tech net.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel: strange, my test table has an id column which is primary key and a unique index on a name column. The `Unique`-property of the DataColumn is set to true on that column as expected with or without a primarykey

Answer (score 2):

Use this to [create a unique index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql) or use the the gui of SSMS.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [name_unique] ON [dbo].[projects]
(
    name ASC
)
```

You have added a unique constraint not a unique index.

Your code now successfully retrieves the `UniqueColumns`(the single column `name`).